# Objective-C TableView not reloading but will clear

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray, nsarray

So im trying to make my table reload after I reload my array.

I can tell the Data is in the array but its not showing up in the table

The table does however update when I set the array equal to nil so I know it has something to do with the way I update the array

EDIT: Ive been trying to debug and I can see the objects in the array but they dont want to reload......

EDIT2: So the UITableView is Printing Nil in the debug box

Header:

```
@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
{
NSMutableArray *historyData;

    NSArray *coords0;
    NSArray *coords1;
    NSArray *coords2;
    NSArray *coords3;
    NSArray *coords4;
    NSArray *coords5;
    NSArray *coords6;
    NSArray *coords7;
    NSArray *coords8;
    NSArray *coords9;


IBOutlet UITableView *tableview;
NSString *LocatedAt;

 }
-(void)setTableValue;
-(NSString *)getAddressForCoords: (NSArray * )coord : (int) number;
 - (IBAction)clearAction:(id)sender;

@property(nonatomic,retain) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@property (nonatomic, retain, readwrite) NSMutableArray *historyData;

@end
```

Methods:

```
 -(void)setTableValue {
 historyData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

if (coords0 != nil)
    [historyData addObject:[self getAddressForCoords:coords0]];
if (coords1 != nil)
    [historyData addObject:[self getAddressForCoords:coords1]];
if (coords2 != nil)
    [historyData addObject:[self getAddressForCoords:coords2]];
if (coords3 != nil)
    [historyData addObject:[self getAddressForCoords:coords3]];
if (coords4 != nil)
    [historyData addObject:[self getAddressForCoords:coords4]];
if (coords5 != nil)
    [historyData addObject:[self getAddressForCoords:coords5]];
if (coords6 != nil)
    [historyData addObject:[self getAddressForCoords:coords6]];
if (coords7 != nil)
    [historyData addObject:[self getAddressForCoords:coords7]];
if (coords8 != nil)
    [historyData addObject:[self getAddressForCoords:coords8]];
if (coords9 != nil)
    [historyData addObject:[self getAddressForCoords:coords9]];

NSLog(@"%@",historyData[0]);
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

}

```
-(NSString *)getAddressForCoords: (NSArray * )coord { //Not done yet 
float lat = [coord[0] floatValue];
float lon = [coord[1] floatValue];

 LocatedAt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Lat: %f Long: %f", lat, lon];

 return LocatedAt;
 }
```

This is what does work...

```
-(IBAction)clearAction:(id)sender
{
   [historyData removeAllObjects];
    NSLog(@"Cleared all memory slots");
    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

Table Methods

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [historyData count];
}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath
{

UITableViewCell *cell = nil;

   cell = [tableview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
}

 //  if ([historyData count] > 0)
    cell.textLabel.text = [historyData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;

 }
```

Comment: Your first method fills an array `historyData`, and the second method clears a different array `arrayData`. - Which one is your table view data source??

Comment: i changed it, its historyData

Comment: (Please always copy/paste your real code!) – Is `setTableValue` called on the main thread or on some background thread?

Comment: main thread and from did load

Comment: So setTableValue is called, but the table view stays empty? - Btw. your method would crash if any of the objects coords0, ..., coords8 is nil. Why don't you use addObject: to append items to the array?

Comment: Can you show UITableViewDataSource methods?

Comment: yes @MartinR and so your saying to not worry about the index and just use addObject?

Comment: It depends on what you want, but an array entry cannot be "empty" or "nil". If you want to append objects sequentially, then just use addObject.

Comment: Is `historyData` a property or an ivar?

Comment: no Alex,  and @MartinR I changed it to [history removeAllObjects] and just addObject but it still is not showing up when I add something

Comment: are you setting a breakpoint in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` to see what it's doing?

Comment: no im not should i be? @bshirley

Comment: Typo on my part.. self.tableView.dataSource = self; not historyData.

Comment: What does getAddressForCoords: do? Do you go out to a server to get this info? Is it an asynchronous process?

Comment: you can often chase this problem with with debugger. break in each of the delegate methods. Often there might be a telltale hint as to what is happening. If you aren't overly familiar with the debugger, take this opportunity to get a little familiar.

Comment: I debugged and I can see the data in the historyData and its there but the table just doesnt show up on the table

Comment: Been playing with the debugger still no luck